# Does orientation change keep the gui values and lose the rest

Tags: java, android

when orientation changes in an activity in my app, the UI stays the same but the variables stored  are gone. so I don't understand whats happening, is a new activity started with only gui configuration or how does the ui retain the same values but variables like Booleans and classes in arrays are reset. and how do I keep my variable values when orientation changes.

Answer (score 1):

Android orientation is handled very interestingly.  When orientation is changed, the activity is destroyed and recreated:  `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()`, respectively.

Google has a good writeup on saving your objects and configurations during such an event:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: I read that page but don't really understand how for example the checkbox after orientation change stays checked and I don't understand how to use onSaveInstanceState to save variables data. do you have any good tutorial you can share with me

Answer (score 0):

Android does indeed destroy the Activity, UI, Fragments, etc. on any configuration change; in this case a orientation change.

As explained [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) there are ways to handle this destruction and recreation: Retained Fragments, Bundles, even overriding and handling the configuration change manually.

To save the state of your variables, you will need to accommodate this change as described [Recreating Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

That all aside, check out Jim White's article: [Intertech Post by Jim White on Save and Restoring Instance State](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/). So the behavior you are seeing is that your local variables and such are being destroyed and re-initialized/created during the configuration change, but the UI seems to be retaining its state while the rest of the application is not. He explains how to save / restore instance state, but also that the UI is automatically saved and restored if the elements are given an ID.